# Video Not streamed in some android devices except Htc

Tags: android, video, streaming

I am trying to stream a video in android device(moto g) which is stored in parse.com uploaded by an IOS device. But I am getting an error message while streaming that video showing "The video Cant be played" in all android device Except HTC.  In Htc the Video is streamed correctly.
    The reason shown for error is "Android MediaPlayer error (1, -2147483648)". and video format is MPEG-4 part 2[image: Here is the video formate details when I downloaded that video in my device]

Answer (score 0):

MPEG-4 Part 2 is the older, now generally deprecated, video compression format that preceded H.264 compression (MPEG-4 Part 10).

Currently, H.264 and AAC encoding are the most widely used formats for media devices.

With nearly any media player you need to be aware of supported formats and know that you'll get that type of error if the media is incompatible.

Not sure why an iOS device would be creating that type of file.

Comment: Ok, Thank you Hankster, I solved that problem by Downloading the video into my devices and then after that playing it from my sd card.

Comment: But I need to use VLC or MX player for running those videos from IOS. Not possible by the default video player.